# Why don't I get any output from this code?

Tags: python, class, printing

```
class Friend:

    def __init__(self,fullname,domicile):
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.domicile = domicile
    
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return ('Friend {}'.format(self.fullname))
    
    
    def first_letter(self):
        firstletter = self.fullname[0]
        print (firstletter)
        return firstletter
    
fnd_1 = Friend('Emilia Asikainen', 'Kintsu')
fnd_2 = Friend('Edi Eskola', 'Muurame')
fnd_3 = Friend('Esa Simonen', 'Jämsä')
fl = ''
fl = fnd_1.first_letter
print(fl)

if fnd_1.first_letter == fnd_2.first_letter and fnd_2.first_letter == fnd_3.first_letter:
    print('Do you have a thing with letter {}?'.format(fnd_1.first_letter))
```

So when I run this code, it doesn't print anything. The only output I get is

Why does my code do this and how can I fix it? I want to get those print methods to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `if fnd_1.first_letter == fnd_2.first_letter and fnd_2.first_letter == fnd_3.first_letter` is not correct, because you're comparing the functions themselves, rather than the output. For instance, `fnd_1.first_letter` is a function; if you want to actually *run* the function, and get its result, you have to use the following syntax: `fnd_1.first_letter()`. Adding the parentheses is necessary in order to actually call a function.

So, if you change your code to correctly call the functions, the relevant part would look like:

```
fl = fnd_1.first_letter()
print(fl)

if fnd_1.first_letter() == fnd_2.first_letter() and fnd_2.first_letter() == fnd_3.first_letter():
    print('Do you have a thing with letter {}?'.format(fnd_1.first_letter()))
```

And the output is:

```
E
E
E
E
E
E
E
Do you have a thing with letter E?
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to invoke your function everywhere. 
To invoke function you should put `()` after name of a function. 
For example replace `fl = fnd_1.first_letter` with `fl = fnd_1.first_letter()` 
And same for `fnd_2` and `fnd_3`.